# InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to store one documents objectID into another as an attribute (linking) but mongo keeps giving me this error. What is wrong with this line's syntax?

```
for u in self.request.db.lyrics.find():
    u['forSong'] = self.request.db.song.find({}, {'_id': 1})
    self.request.db.lyrics.save(u)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the result of **find** method is a cursor, not a list of objects

```
u['forSong'] = self.request.db.song.find({}, {'_id': 1})
```

is cursor, not an object.
So you must convert returned cursor to list for doing your task:

```
u['forSong'] = list(self.request.db.song.find({}, {'_id': 1}))
```

That will save **list of dicts like {'_id': object-id}** into "forSong" field.
To actually receive list of object ids you must make further conversion, e.g:

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
u['forSong'] = map(itemgetter('_id'),
                   list(self.request.db.song.find({}, {'_id': 1})))
```

Comment: What if I want to store the _id object itself, not a list?

Comment: No, it's a dict with 1 key '_id', which value is mongo's ObjectId. You must fetch values from these dicts to receive plain list of ObjectId objects, as I've added in my updated answer above

Comment: I've changed my lines to for u in self.request.db.lyrics.find():
            u['forSong'] = map(itemgetter('_id'), list(self.request.db.song.find({}, {'_id': 1}))
            self.request.db.lyrics.save(u) but I'm still getting a syntax error

Comment: Well, my mistake, there's one parenthesis I've dropped in the end.

Comment: Is the syntax for itemgetter correct? I'm getting NameError: global name 'itemgetter' is not defined

Comment: You've possibly missed import: *from operator import itemgetter*.